# Where can I find SqsListener

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-cloud, amazon-sqs

We are trying to use [spring-cloud-aws](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html) to receive messages from AWS SQS

We would like to receive messages using annotation. In spring [documentation](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html#_annotation_driven_listener_endpoints), it is confusing.

Below, they stated to use MessageMapping and QueueMessageHandler annotation.

> Annotation-driven listener endpoints are the easiest way for listening
>   on SQS messages. Simply annotate methods with MessageMapping and the
>   QueueMessageHandler will route the messages to the annotated methods.

But in the sample, @SQSListener is used.

```
@SqsListener("queueName")
public void queueListener(Person person) {
    // ...
}
```

I searched for @SqsListener and found that it is being used in test classes like [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/blob/master/spring-cloud-aws-integration-test/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/aws/messaging/QueueListenerTest.java#L173) . So we tried to import, `org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.annotation.SqsListener`. Unfortunately this annotation class is not available in latest release.

Is the `org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.annotation.SqsListener` that I am using is proper one? Or it is not yet present in released version? If not released can I use `@MessageMapping` to receive messages from SQS?

Comment: @Alian - Do you have any clue with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to not be included in the 1.0.4 release of Spring Cloud AWS however I was able to successfully import SqsListener when using 1.1.0.RC1

You need to add:

```
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-aws:1.1.0.RC1'
        mavenBom "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:1.3.3.RELEASE"
    }
```

Additionally the messaging dependency needs to be added (and I've got actuator included too):

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws")
    compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-messaging")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
}
```

Note, I haven't tested it to see if it can actually consume a message of SQS but at least the dependency is resolving.

Answer (score 3):

I am using the 1.1.0.RELEASE, that's the dependencies I have:

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:1.3.5.RELEASE")
compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging:1.1.0.RELEASE")
```

I tried both annotations @SqsListener and @MessageMapping both work fine. The SqsListener is a specialization of the MessageMapping annotation which is adding an additional property, the deletion policy.

I am guessing the documentation has to be updated, I got confused as well.

Answer (score 0):

Now @SqsListener available with  1.1.0.RELEASE.